# Like в Linq .Net

Tags: oracle, linq, sql

Всем доброго здравия.
Возник вопрос, на который ответа практически никак найти не могу.
Я создал тему на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527499/linq-like-or-other-construction), но там вразумительного ответа так и не дождался. Может из-за не понимания моего корявого английского, может по другим причинам.
Суть проблемы вот в чем:
У меня есть репозиторий. Я выбираю данные, используя `linq`. В `Linq` есть несколько видов выбора данных. Я все перепробовал - ни один не подходит.
Пример запроса:

```
select * from doctor where doctor.name
like '%IVANOV_A%';
```

Я ищу в базе докторов по полной фамилии и начальной букве имени. Возможны варианты вообще без имени. База довольно огромная, порядка 300.000 строк. Все давнные записаны примерно в таком виде(имею ввиду поле NAME) "IVANOV IVAN".

Пример:

```
string[] mass = name.Split(' '); // где name - вводимая пользователем строка.
return from p in repository.Doctor.Where(x =>
x.ClinicId == clinicId)
where(from m in mass where m.Contains(p.Name.ToLower()))
select p;
```

Выбирает только по фамилии, а вот если добавляется что-то типо "IVANOV I", вместо "IVANOV", то уже никакого результата не получаю.

Пример:

```
return from p in repository.Doctor from m in mass where
mass.Any( i => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(i)) && p.ClinicId == clinicId
select p;
```

Здесь по идее, должна быть выборка любых совпадений, но нет - при вводе "IVANOV I", начинает искать по правилу "I" нахождения в слове, потому как "I" - 2-й элемент массива "mass"

Пример

```
return from p in repository.Doctor
where p.Name.ToLower().Contains(firstname) && 
p.Name.ToLower().Contains(secondname)
&& p.ClinicId == clinicId
select p
```

По идее, я уже заведомо разделил пользовательский ввод "`IVANOV I`" на 2 составляющие и передал их в конструкцию. Но и этот вариант тоже не проходит.

Пример

```
return from p in repository.Doctor where 
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like(p.Name.ToLower(), name) select p;
```

Но тут косяк. Я использую Oracle как базу, и для меня `System.Data.Linq` уже не доступен.
Такой метод как говорят многие мануалы - просто недопустим.

Вот поэтому у меня вопрос. Может кто подскажет, есть или нормальная конструкци `LIKE` в `linq` или может я допустил какие-то ошибки при логичном составлении самого запроса.

### **P.S. Не обращайте вримания на toLower(), toUpper() - суть не в этом.**

```
P.S.S:
```

Есть БД. С таблицами. В ней есть строки. Есть `id, name, clinicId`. Пользователь при вводе на странице через `autocmplite jquery` вводит фамилию и имя, при преодалении 5 символов посылается на сервер запрос с тем, что ввел пользователь на странице. Основной вид пользовательского ввода, например, "IVANOV " - тогда ищет всех Ивановых в базе и выдает результат(пагинацию и ограничения опустим). Допустим нашло их 1000 человек. Выдало. Он вводит дальше в строку - "IVANOV "(после фамилии пробел идет). Опять производится поиск по строке в базе на совпадения. Допустим осталось уже 850 результатов. Пользователь продолжает ввод. Ввводит "IVANOV I" - опять запрос, опять вывод, уже, к примеру 500. "IVANOV_IVAN" - как конечный результат поиска, к примеру, вывело 350 человек. Я использую `Linq` для получения данных из класса-репозитория. Каким образом он реализован и все остальное - описывать очень долго. Мне нужна универсальная конструкция `Like` или объяснение, в чем у меня проблема при выборке. Все замечания, типо "`uppercase, lowercase`, зачем разбиваешь на фамилию и имя" не относящиеся к теме - игнорируются.

Comment: @sombik, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Как-то туманно. Можно простенький пример, который можно было бы запустить и увидеть, что работает, а что нет? А продираться через "поток сознания" совсем неохота.

Comment: Для меня последний вариант работает (разделенный на 2 параметра), предыдущий не корректный запрос. И еще мне кажется нет смысла делить на имя и фамилию параметр - проще искать, если он в нужном формате.

Comment: @sombik Только честно, Вы ведь сюда не за ответом пришли?

     where(from m in mass where m.Contains(p.Name.ToLower())) select p;

Что тут в чём должно быть? "IVANOV A" в "IVANOV"? Если нет, то напишите чуть понятнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно насчет like в Linq не всё так гладко.
Некоторое время назад данная проблема у нас была решена примерно так:

```
[System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmFunction("WebDataModel", "String_Like")]
public static bool Like(this string input, string pattern)
{
    /* Turn "off" all regular expression related syntax in
     * the pattern string. */
    pattern = Regex.Escape(pattern);

    /* Replace the SQL LIKE wildcard metacharacters with the
     * equivalent regular expression metacharacters. */
    pattern = pattern.Replace("%", ".*?").Replace("_", ".");

    /* The previous call to Regex.Escape actually turned off
     * too many metacharacters, i.e. those which are recognized by
     * both the regular expression engine and the SQL LIKE
     * statement ([...] and [^...]). Those metacharacters have
     * to be manually unescaped here. */
    pattern = pattern.Replace(@"\[", "[").Replace(@"\]", "]").Replace(@"\^", "^");

    return Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

**input** - поле, где необходимо произвести поиск,

**pattern** - маска по которой ищем.

Ну и как принято говорить "пунктуация автора сохранена"...

Comment: Спасибо, не ожидал такого сильного ответа, благодарю.